# Awk not working in bash script when use variable in comparison

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Following is my bash script. If I use varible oid to compare in awk, it doesnt show matching line.

```
oid="3586302804992"
SYMBOL_CSV_FILE="symbol/BAC"
awk -F, '$5 == $oid' "$SYMBOL_CSV_FILE"
echo "2nd"
awk -F, '$5 == "3586302804992"' "$SYMBOL_CSV_FILE"
```

O/P  is

```
2nd
BAC,1,O,1,3586302804992
```

`symbol/BAK` file contents are

```
BAC,1,O,1,3586302804992o
```

Putting "" around $oid , on 3rd line, doesnt make any difference.

Comment: To use bash variables inside an `awk` script, you need to "pass" them with `-v`. For example `num=3; awk -v n=$num 'BEGIN{print n}'`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of:

```
awk -F, '$5 == $oid' "$SYMBOL_CSV_FILE"
```

use it like this:

```
awk -F "," -v oid="$oid" '$5 == oid' "$SYMBOL_CSV_FILE"
```

Comment: thanks, Worked in right way. @Anubhava: the variable passing mechanism to awk has any specific reason?

Comment: Yes `-v` is standard way to pass variables from shell to awk. These variable then become standard awk variables and you can use them without quoting or `$` inside awk scripts.

Answer (score 1):

For bash to interpret your variables, you have to use the double quotes. Single quotes will send `$oid` as is to your program.

Then, as the `$5` will also be interpreted, and you don't want to! You have to escape the `$`.

In the end, you have:

```
awk -F, "\$5 == $oid" "$SYMBOL_CSV_FILE"
        ^^          ^
```

Comment: Giving error as                                                   awk:  == 3586302804992
awk:  ^ syntax error
2nd
BAC,1,O,1,3586302804992

Comment: @rahul.deshmukhpatil Fixed with escaping the $5. Thanks for pointing this out.